# How to convert signed numbers in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, signed

I have a table that contains signed numbers ('123C' = 1233). Is there a way to convert these numbers in a select statement in PL/SQL (ie. +1233) so I can load them into another table? I am not really even sure how to google that question.

Thanks!

Comment: Share more input data and desired output for each row. It is a bit unclear for me now

Comment: Why is '123C' = 1233? Because C is the third letter of the alphabet and you're storing things in a strange mixed format? Or is it really hexadecimal (123C = 4668), or something else? (Not sure what this has to do with the sign anyway though)

Comment: I'm guessing that 'A', 'B', ...,  'J' represent the sign-digits +1, +2, ..., +0. How are the negative sign-digits represented?

Comment: Bob is correct in his assumption that 'A' - 'I' are positive 1-9 and 'J' - 'R' are negatives. And then there are { and } for +/- 0. I am not sure what these types of numbers are ....IBM signed? Obviously, I can not use them as signed. So I am looking for a way to convert them.

Comment: J-R are negative what; J is -1 and R is -9, or the other way around? What about zero? Can you edit the question to explain the storage mechanism and give some sample data and expected output?

Comment: 8268D = +82684, 680G = +6807, 269M = -2694, 525R = -5259

Comment: It would be better to have an explanation and examples in the question, rather than just in comments. And how do you store a number that ends in a zero - with a curly brace, `}' perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rule that the last character represents +1 as A, +2 as B, +3 as C, etc.; and -1 as J, -2 as K, -3 as L etc., you can do a two-stage conversion. First replace the last character with the corresponding digit:

```
translate(value, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR', '123456789123456789')
```

You could do something with ASCII comparison but a simple list is probably clearer here. And then convert that to a number:

```
to_number(translate(value, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR', '123456789123456789'))
```

And then multiply by -1 if the last character was in the negative range:

```
case when substr(value, -1) >= 'J' then -1 else 1 end
```

Demo with your sample values:

```
with t (value) as (
  select '123C' from dual
  union all select '8268D' from dual
  union all select '680G' from dual
  union all select '269M' from dual
  union all select '535R' from dual
)
select value,
  to_number(translate(value, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR', '123456789123456789'))
      * case when substr(value, -1) >= 'J' then -1 else 1 end as converted
from t;

VALUE  CONVERTED
----- ----------
123C        1233
8268D      82684
680G        6807
269M       -2694
525R       -5259
```

You could put all of that in a function if you'll use it a lot but it's fairly simple to repeat as needed.

But you haven't specified how you represent the last digit being a zero. If you're using ['zoned decimal'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Zoned_decimal) then you can include those in the `translate()` call:

```
translate(value, '{ABCDEFGHI}JKLMNOPQR', '01234567890123456789')
```

But the sign calculation is a little more awkward as you can't just use character set order; again brute-force but clear, you can just compare the last character to decide if it's positive or negative:

```
    case when substr(value, -1) in ('J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', '}')
      then -1 else 1 end
```

As a function just for fun:

```
create function decode_zoned_decimal(p_value in varchar2) return number is
begin
  return to_number(translate(p_value, '{ABCDEFGHI}JKLMNOPQR', '01234567890123456789'))
    * case when substr(p_value, -1) in ('J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', '}')
        then -1 else 1 end;
end;
/
```

And testing with some additional values:

```
with t (value) as (
  select '123C' from dual
  union all select '8268D' from dual
  union all select '680G' from dual
  union all select '269M' from dual
  union all select '525R' from dual
  union all select '123{' from dual
  union all select '123}' from dual
)
select value, decode_zoned_decimal(value) as converted
from t;

VALUE  CONVERTED
----- ----------
123C        1233
8268D      82684
680G        6807
269M       -2694
525R       -5259
123{        1230
123}       -1230
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: @Marianne - I've updated it to handle positive and negative zero as the last character. I've assumed you have those as curly braces. You may need to modify it slightly if that isn't the case.

Comment: Thank you, Alex! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

123C sounds as *COMP-3 number style*

maybe the link will be useful: [AskTom, Comp-3 converting](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:228813971094)